# In Ajax response my if condition is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Check the `jquery` code bellow. Here after process post request the `response` returning `no_file_found` but if condition not meeting and not hitting `alert()`. Whats wrong i am doing here?

```
$("#btnFoo").on("click", function () {
            var file_data = $('#formUploadImg').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            form_data.append('ProId', $(this).attr("img-upload-product-id"));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/mycontroller/upload',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(typeof response);//it returns string
                    if (response == "no_file_found") {
                        alert("this not hits");//this alert not hits
                    }
                    
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
```

Please note i am using c# mvc5 and the response is comming from mvc5 controller. Mvc5 example bellow:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult upload()
{
    return Json("no_file_found");
}
```

Comment: check `console.log(response, response == "no_file_found")`... is this logging "no_file_found" and true?

Comment: it shows: `"no_file_found" false` and why it is false any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function to make sure all **unseen** `spaces` are removed from the `response` to be able to `match` the exact comparison`==` of `no_file_found`.

**Edit:** The reason it is `not` working is because you are returning `"no_file_found"` with double quotes **""** added. But on the front end you are checking simply `no_file_found` - You need to use `replace` function to make sure all the double quotes are `deleted` from the `response`.

```js
var response = '"no_file_found"';
if (response.replace(/["']/g, "").trim() == "no_file_found") {
  alert("this hits"); //this alert hits
 }
```

Comment: good though bro but this is not the case even. weird

Comment: @DillGates Are you sure you are getting this response from the ajax as `no_file_found` - can you check the network console by clicking F12 and see what coming in the response of that actually ajax call

Comment: https://ibb.co/LhVvx8c check here i have attached screen shot of Network tab from browser dev tool

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are returning a Json value  - but your ajax is set to have a dataType: 'text'.

If you change dataType: 'json' all works as expeceted.